# listing sub menu items under their parent

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a table with several columns that looks something like this:

```
id  parent__id  title  body  navdepth  navorder navitem
1    0          home    xx      0         1       1
2    1          about   xx      1         2       1
3    2          child   xx      2         1       1
4    3          subchild x      3         1       1
```

I am querying the table like this to get the title for navigation.

```
<cfquery name="getnavigation">
  SELECT
    c1.id,
    c1.title,
    c1.parent__id,
    c1.nav_depth,
    c1.nav_order
  FROM content AS c1

  LEFT JOIN content AS c2
  ON c1.id = c2.parent__id
  WHERE 0 = 0
  AND c1.is_nav_item = 1
  GROUP BY c1.id
  ORDER BY c1.nav_depth, c1.nav_order
</cfquery>
```

I want to display the pages of nav_depth 0 to 1 as parent pages in case any page has children to be listed on dropdown.

I have tried this but it is showing all the pages as parent:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse" role="navigation">                                     
  <ul class="nav top-2">
    <cfset local.level1 = -1 />
    <cfset local.level2 = -1 />
    <cfloop query="navigation">
        <cfset local.level2 = navigation.nav_depth>
    <cfif local.level2 GT local.level1>
      <li><a href="#buildUrl(navigation.title)#" class="<cfif local.level1 EQ -1><cfelse>dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown</cfif>">#navigation.title#</a>                 
      <cfelseif local.level2 LT local.level1>
      <cfset local.temp = local.level1 />
      <cfloop condition="local.temp GT local.level2">
        </li>
        <cfset local.temp -= 1 />
      </cfloop>
      </li><li><a href="#buildUrl(navigation.title)#">#navigation.title#</a>
    <cfelse>
      </li><li><a href="#buildUrl(navigation.title)#">#navigation.title#</a>                        
    </cfif>
    <cfset local.level1 = navigation.nav_depth />
    </cfloop>
    <cfset local.temp = local.level1 />
    <cfloop condition="local.temp GT 0">
        </li>
    <cfset local.temp -= 1 />
    </cfloop>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /nav-collapse -->
```

Is there any way to display child items under their parent other than this?

Comment: Is there a common piece of information you can group on? You could then use the `group` attribute of `cfoutput query`

Comment: yeah, that's the issue everything is varying upon adding new records and level gets increases. but at each level the id and parentid are same. it is the only that is common.

Comment: If the current order by clause puts your query records in the order you want them displayed, the group attribute might work.  You might have to use it twice, but that's ok.  Otherwise, it's unlikely that anything will work.  Focus on that.

Comment: @DanBracuk - even i also trying to displaying using cfoutput query it is too simple.